# Deploy report to JasperServer via SOAP API

Tags: java, soap, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am looking for an example on deploying a report unit to JasperServer using it's SOAP Services, preferably with a java client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do that with `JasperServer WebServices` (Set of SOAP services for managing server and data on it).

So ... the unit of data used to communicate with the server is  `com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.xml.domain.impl.ResourceDescriptor`... which represents a resource... implementation of client is the following `com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.irplugin.wsclient.WSClient`...

to make it a bit clearer here is the code :

```
public void publishImage() throws Exception {

    ResourceDescriptor rd = new ResourceDescriptor();       
    rd.setName("coffeepicture");
    rd.setLabel("Coffee picture from java");
    rd.setResourceType(ResourceDescriptor.TYPE_IMAGE);
    rd.setMainReport(true);
    rd.setParentFolder("/Samples");
    rd.setUriString(rd.getParentFolder() + rd.getName());
    rd.setWsType(ResourceDescriptor.TYPE_IMAGE);
    rd.setIsNew(true);
    rd.setHasData(true);

    File image = new File("/home/coffee.jpg");

    client.addOrModifyResource(rd, image);
}
```

The code above shows how to upload an image to the server, to deploy a report you will need to create separate `ResourceDescriptors` for `.jrxml` file and datasource if any...

Regards!